# Strange error when open workbook on tableau desktop

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api

I try to open a workbook on Tableau Desktop version 10.3, 10.4 and 10.5 but it is showing an error. I don't know exactly which Tableau Desktop version is used to create the workbook. My Tableau Server version is 10.3, so I tried to open it in Tableau Desktop version 10.3, 10.4 and 10.5.

The error message:

```
Error(30913,25): no declaration found for element 'zone-style' (id: C:\Users\kashif\AppData\
Local\Temp\TableauTemp\1498627980\InsuredDashboardNewLayout.twb)
Error(30918,18): element 'zone-style' is not allowed for content model '(formatted-text,layout-
cache?,zone,flipboard)' (id: C:\Users\kashif\AppData\Local\Temp\TableauTemp\1498627980\
InsuredDashboardNewLayout.twb) Error(30923,25): no declaration found for element
'zone-style' (id: C:\Users\kashif\AppData\Local\Temp\TableauTemp\1498627980\
InsuredDashboardNewLayout.twb) Error(30928,18): element 'zone-style' is not
allowed for content model '(formatted-text,layout-cache?,zone,flipboard)' (id: C:\Users\kashif\
AppData\Local\Temp\TableauTemp\1498627980\InsuredDashboardNewLayout.twb)
Error(30933,25): no declaration found for element 'zone-style' (id: C:\Users\kashif\AppData\
Local\Temp\TableauTemp\1498627980\InsuredDashboardNewLayout.twb)
Error(30938,18): element 'zone-style' is not allowed for content model '(formatted-text,layout-
cache?,zone,flipboard)' (id: C:\Users\kashif\AppData\Local\Temp\TableauTemp\1498627980\
InsuredDashboardNewLayout.twb)
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like the workbook is from a newer version of Tableau than 10.3, 10.4, and 10.5. If you are able to try updating to the newest version of Tableau and see if the issue is still there.

Someone had a similar issue in the thread below.

https://community.tableau.com/thread/264782